# nodejs + mongoose - query aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this schema on my node.js app. I'm using mongoose:

```
var todoSchema = new Schema({
  task: String,
  description: String,
  date: Date,
  status: String,
  checklist: Boolean,
  user: String
});
```

I want to get this result, so I can pass it into google chart and display it on chart:

```
[
  {
    "user": "A",
    "detail" :
    [
      "open" : 3,
      "progress" : 5,
      "done" : 7
      "archive" : 10
    ]
  },
  {
    "user": "B",
    "detail" :
    [
      "open" : 4,
      "progress" : 9,
      "done" : 14
      "archive" : 12
    ]
  }
]
```

But my query looks wrong:

```
Todo.find().distinct( "user", function(err, users){
    Todo.find({"user": {"$in": users}}, function(err, todo){
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      var finalResult = [];
      finalResult.push(todo);
      res.send(finalResult);
      //res.send(todo);
    });
  });
});
```

Anybody can help me, please? Really appreciated your help.

Comment: You are specifing "pic" field inside distinct method, but I don't see that field inside your todoSchema. Do you get any error?

Comment: @NikolaB. sorry for the typo. I already edited my post and changed it into user. thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)** and run the following aggregation pipeline which uses two **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** and $project pipeline steps; the first one is to group your documents by the `user` field and use the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator in the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** accumulator operator expression to evaluate the counts based on the status field. The second **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step will add the `detail` array by using the accumulator operator **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** that returns an array of expression values for each group. The last step **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** will modify the document fields by renaming the `_id` field to `user`:

```
var pipeline = [
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$user",             
            "open_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "open" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "progress_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "progress" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "done_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "done" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "archive_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "archive" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            } 
        }  
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",            
            "detail": {
                "$push": {
                    "open": "$open_count",
                    "progress": "$progress_count",
                    "done": "$done_count",
                    "archive": "$archive_count"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "user": "$_id", "detail": 1
        }
    }
];


Todo.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, result){
    if (err) res.send(err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 4));
    res.send(result);
})
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm sorry for my stupidity to asking question like that, I'm still learning about mongodb and nodejs. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @lamfete No worries, always happy to help :-) If this answers your question, consider marking the [**answer as accepted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). You can do so by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time. Note, there is no obligation in accepting the answer, but feel free to do so as that's the norm around here. Also consider doing the exercise to your other questions. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know before to toggle check list beside the answer. I already clicked it for this post and my post before which is you answered it too :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Simply gets all of your todos. 
Do not forget to `return` when handling errors

```
Todo.find({}, function(err, todos){
    if (err)
        return res.send(err);

    res.send(todos)
})
```