# nodejs + mongodb error exception: FieldPath 'progress' doesn't start with $

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to modify the second pipeline from this query (which I got from here [nodejs + mongoose - query aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871588/nodejs-mongoose-query-aggregate)

```
db.todos.aggregate([
{ 
  "$group": { 
      "_id": "$pic",             
      "open_count": {
          "$sum": {
              "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "open" ] }, 1, 0 ]
          }
      },
      "progress_count": {
          "$sum": {
              "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "progress" ] }, 1, 0 ]
          }
      },
      "done_count": {
          "$sum": {
              "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "done" ] }, 1, 0 ]
          }
      },
      "archive_count": {
          "$sum": {
              "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "archive" ] }, 1, 0 ]
          }
      } 
  }  
},
{
  "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",            
      "detail": {
          "$push": {
              "name": "open",
              "$todos": "$open_count"
          },
          "$push": {
              "name": "progress",
              "$todos": "$progress_count"
          },
          "$push": {
              "name": "done",
              "$todos": "$done_count"
          },
          "$push": {
              "name": "archive",
              "$todos": "$archive_count"
          }
      }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
      "_id": 0, "pic": "$_id", "detail": 1
  }
}
])
```

I want this kind of JSON structure so I can put it on google chart, which the format is like this:

```
[
    {
        "pic": "A",
        "detail": [
            {
                "name": "open",
                "todos": 2
            },
            {
                "name": "progress",
                "todos": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "done",
                "todos": 8
            },
            {
                "name": "archive",
                "todos": 20
            }
        ],
        "pic": "B",
        "detail": [
            {
                "name": "open",
                "todos": 5
            },
            {
                "name": "progress",
                "todos": 2
            },
            {
                "name": "done",
                "todos": 5
            },
            {
                "name": "archive",
                "todos": 10
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

But I got this error

```
exception: FieldPath 'progress' doesn't start with $
```

Comment: Any chance it points to a line number? YOu have a few instances of `progress` in there

Comment: @DavidGrinberg no, there is no information of line number in the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this aggregation query:

```
db.todos.aggregate([
  {
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "pic": "$pic",
      "name": "$status"
    },
    "todos": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "pic": "$_id.pic",
    "detail": {
      "name": "$_id.name",
      "todos": "$todos"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$pic",
    "detail": {
      "$push": "$detail"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0, "pic": "$_id", "detail": 1
}
}])
```

Comment: your aggregation query only sum status: "open". Another status ("progress", "done", and "archive") is 0. How to sum another status and add it into the result?

Comment: Oops my bad. Edited the answer